# For loop trouble across compilers

Tags: c, xcode

I am having trouble. My program seems to work fine on DEV C++,but on Xcode the last For loop doesn't know when to stop. any help?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>           
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>          

void strip_newline(char *str,int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        if(str[i]=='\n')
        {
            str[i]='\0';
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main()    
{
    int randomnumber; 
    int max;           
    int tall;        
    char name[40][tall]; 
    char seat[40][tall]; 
    int count;           
    int currentcount;
    int flag;

    srand( time(NULL) ); 
    printf("Enter total number of students: "); 
    scanf("%d",&max); 
    getchar();        
    tall=max+1;       
    randomnumber=rand()% max +1; 
    printf("This is your random number\n %d \n",randomnumber); 
    printf("Enter your students names and press enter after each name:\n "); 

    fgets(name[0],40,stdin); 
    strip_newline(name[0],40); 

    for(count=1; count < max; count++ )
    {    
        printf("Please enter next name\n ");
        fgets(name[count],40,stdin);  
        strip_newline(name[count],40);
    }

    count=-1;

    do {
        randomnumber=rand()% max;
        flag=0;
        for(currentcount=0; currentcount<max; currentcount++)
        {
            if(strcmp(name[randomnumber],seat[currentcount])==0)
            {
               flag=1;
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            strcpy(seat[count],name[randomnumber]);
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    while (count != max);

    for(count=0; count < max; count++)
    {
        printf("%s sits in seat %d\n",seat[count],count+1);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Cleaning up your indentation and unnecessary newlines would make your code far more readable.

Comment: Your code was... differently formated.  Please consider making this easier for people in the future - it is easier to help someone who has shown the time to format the code than reading a jumbled mess.  Furthermore, what inputs does it have difficulty with?  All of them? Some of them? What are they? Consider also reducing the program to the minimum size that demonstrates the bug rather than ~80 lines of C.

Comment: Don't know whether that's the cause, but at the point where `name` and `seat` are declared, `tall` is uninitialised, so there's no knowing what size the arrays get. Also, `fgets(name[0],40,stdin);` looks like you'd want `char name[some_dim][40];`.

Comment: You are potentially reading from uninitialized memory here: `strcmp(name[randomnumber],seat[currentcount])`

Comment: Can you guarantee that `strcmp(name[randomnumber],seat[currentcount])` will return 0?  If not, that while loop goes forever.

Comment: `int tall;        
    char name[40][tall];` <- tail is not initialize.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, had to go somewhere in a hurry. How is tall uninitialized? Didn't I declare it?

Comment: @Tohrik If you didn't have to read it in a hurry, it would have been nice for you to format it before posting it.  It hasn't helped anything to have posted it earlier and given us more work.  --- Declaring doesn't mean initializing.  Until you write `tall = 42;` or the like, it doesn't have a defined value (its behavior may change from compiler to compiler).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
int tall;        
char name[40][tall]; 
char seat[40][tall];
```

as `tall` is not initialized (not given a value), it is unknown how large your 40 arrays will become. It could be anything between 0 and a very large number, or even 'blow-up-in-your-face' as the behaviour is formally undefined. The later assignment to `tall` will not magically resize the arrays for you.

The solution is to re-arrange your code such that the arrays are not declared until you have sufficient information about their size. Also, given how you use them, you seem to want `tall` arrays of 40 characters, not 40 arrays of `tall` characters, so you need to swap the dimensions:

```
//...
printf("Enter total number of students: "); 
scanf("%d",&max); 
getchar();        
tall=max+1;       
char name[tall][40]; 
char seat[tall][40]; 
//...
```